# Ubuntu make and its other uses including use in installation of android studio

Tags: ubuntu-make

What is Ubuntu Make?
And what other developer tools can we download from Ubuntu make?

Do I have to install Ubuntu Make every time while downloading other developer tools from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the description from the package `ubuntu-make`

> Ubuntu Make is a command line tool which allows you to download the
>   latest version of popular developer tools on your installation,
>   installing it along side all the required dependencies (which will only
>   ask for root access if you don't have all the required dependencies
>   installed already), enable multi-arch on your system if you are on a
>   64 bit machine, integrate it with the Unity launcher… Basically, one
>   command to get your system ready to develop with! `

Here is [the documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

> Do I have to install it every time or is it a file to be downloaded
>   only once

Only once it is a package to install other packages, once you install it, it will stay, use this command to install it

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-developer-tools-center
```

> What other developer tools can we download from Ubuntu make?

Some examples included

Android studio

```
umake android
```

The eclipse IDE

```
umake ide eclipse
```

The other packages you can install with this:

`arduino`, `idea`, `rubymine`, `pycharm`, `phpstorm`, `pycharm-educational`, `idea-ultimate`, `pycharm-professional`,`webstorm`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As you are a new user if this helps you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to easily find this information

Comment: @mark..so what other developer tools can we download from umake??      And do i have to install it everytime or is it a file to be downloaded only once?

Comment: Updated to reflect your edit.

Comment: @mark..I have used this to install ubuntu make..                                                         sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make..It worked I guess and one thing does ubuntu-make has a version and how will I know if it has been installed correctly or not?

Comment: To know if it is installed, run it, just type `umake` you will get a manual if it is installed. The version on 15.10 is `umake 15.08`

Comment: actually I had to install Android Studio,so I used this three commands.                                                                                                                              $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
$ sudo apt-get update                                                                                                          $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make                                                                            $ umake android..?So is it correct?

Comment: Actually, I did some research and they are the same thing, just renamed, so any way is fine.

Comment: Ok..so last thing should I install it after the installation of android studio or right now??Android studio installation is currently going on..

Comment: You already installed it, that is how you can use the command `umake android` without this you could not call `umake`

Comment: oh..sorry..yup exactly boss..thanks for making me understand bdw..:)